# SaveChanges() overhead

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

When calling `DbContext.SaveChanges()`, is there any performance benefit to checking whether there are any changes to be saved? For example:

```
if (context.ChangeTracker.HasChanges())
    context.SaveChanges()
```

Or is this the kind of check that EF is performing internally when `SaveChanges()` is called?

Answer (score 2):

Internally, EF does a check to determine whether changes have been made, and it will not commit anything (so it won't waste resources), if there were no changes.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```js
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
Stopwatch sw2 = new Stopwatch();

sw.Start();
    var b = db.ChangeTracker.HasChanges();
sw.Stop();

sw2.Start();
    var c = db.SaveChanges();
sw2.Stop();



Console.WriteLine("Elapsed(HasChanges)={0}", sw.Elapsed); //takes 0.0000889 miliseconds
Console.WriteLine("Elapsed(SaveChanges)={0}", sw2.Elapsed); // takes 0.0003563 miliseconds
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.